# post deployment to google cloud the site seems down

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a pretty basic website(having html/css/js codes) to be hosted at google cloud. I went into the server pulled in the code and tried to build it.

```
cd /opt/my_project_name/src
git pull && npm run build
systemctl restart my_project_name
```

There was no error during the process. But when I am hitting to the website it seems down. Tried to stop/start the vm instance but no help yet!

Answer (score 0):

General checks:

- Is the instance up?
- Can you SSH into the instance?
- On the instance: Is something running which should answer on port 80 ( or whichever port you are using?
- On the instance: Use lynx and try to access your site. ( If if fails, the issue is with your code, build, local server.)
- If it works locally then check the firewall rules, routing
- Try to telnet the instance on the specific port